# Open Excel Application and Save file with python

Tags: python, html, excel, pandas

I am trying to open a HTML file in Microsoft Excel from python and save as an excel/csv file. I have the script below to open the file but cannot find a way to save it once open.

```
import os

os.system("start EXCEL.EXE export.05.25.2022.html")
```

My goal is to automate this script where it can open excel and save it from a HTML file and save it as a CSV.

Comment: Here what you are doing is just calling a system command to open a file using MS-Excel.
It's only as good as you double click and open the file. Do you expect the program to do what "Save as xlsx" does from MS-Excel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this way you only open file in external program (`Excel`) and python doesn't have control on this external program. It may need to use module like [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to control `mouse` and `keyboard` and then you can use `mouse`/`keyboard` to control `Excel`. Eventually you may try modules which may use `win32` to control external programs in Windows. ie. [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)